# Have you ever heard "Position" design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, data-structures

In these days, I'm studying data structure. In my [data structure book](http://goo.gl/0d7lq), the author said, "We'll use 'Position' design pattern" -> [Photo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgk6gur2x6mzouc/2012-11-14%2021.15.14.jpg)

So I googled the *Position* design pattern because I wanted to know about it. However, I couldn't find any results. :'(

The author said, "The reason why we use *Position* design pattern is that we do not wish to allow user to modify internal structure." -> [Photo 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/elr8zosfhzpuh1e/2012-11-14%2018.58.52.jpg) [Photo 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dk2v0ln9jlp2l2/2012-11-14%2019.00.18.jpg)
(e.g. not exposing method for accessing link when we return node element)

I absolutely agree with the author's opinion and intention, but I can't be sure about the word 'design pattern'

Comment: That sounds more like a linked list (and a little bit like the composite pattern if implemented as a tree with child-nodes) to me.

Comment: @Felix I know it is linked list. However, the position design pattern is used to not only linked list but also tree structure in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Position Pattern probably isn't as well known these days as most developers are working at a higher level of abstraction. We are using implementations of the position pattern when we use certain operations on collections - but we aren't implementing it ourselves.

[Opinion] You are more likely to find references to The Position Pattern in books that talk about lower level programming. Perhaps alongside The Iterator Pattern, for example, which many developers will never implement themselves but will use an implementation when they spin up a `for each` loop.

Comment: Thanks! So.. Is `Position Pattern` exact name? or it has more appropriate name?

Comment: I have heard it called the "Position Pattern", so anecdotally speaking I'm sure that this is the name, rather than it only occurring under that name in the book you have.